# Varnish/Symfony3 Cache on Nginx - Ago 0 on caching

Tags: caching, docker, symfony, varnish

I've set up varnish via Docker on my Symfony build but can;t get the caching to work properly. Age seems to stay at 0 no matter what I try.

From reading about it may be to do with cookies being set or possibly expires headers but I cant for the life of me work out what's happening.

Response headers are:

```
Age:0
Cache-Control:max-age=64000, public, s-maxage=64000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 29 Sep 2016 20:21:43 GMT
ETag:"cb3ed8f6672c4be1148c4f7d12c20789"
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:device_view=full; expires=Sat, 29-Oct-2016 20:21:43 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language
Via:1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache-Debug:1
X-Cache-Debug:1
X-Debug-Token:503eda
X-Debug-Token-Link:http://192.168.99.100/app_dev.php/_profiler/503eda
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.11
X-Varnish:65542
```

Request headers are:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:customcookie=1; _gat=1; PHPSESSID=1fd8cd59c8d8d0185310ec0cdb06fce7; _ga=GA1.1.706323429.1474891952; hl=en; device_view=full
Host:192.168.99.100
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
```

Current VCL file:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "192.168.99.100";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.Forwarded;

    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto == "https" ) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Port = "443";
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Port = "80";
    }

    // Remove all cookies except the session ID.
    if (req.http.Cookie) {
        set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(PHPSESSID)=", "; \1=");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

        if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
            // If there are no more cookies, remove the header to get page cached.
            unset req.http.Cookie;
        }
    }
}
```

Changing to the below has no effect:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.Forwarded;
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}
```

I'm guessing it'll be something simple, but cannot get this to work. Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you add the response headers from your nginx when you request it directly (without varnish)? Plus you are using the `Pragma:no-cache` header in your request, you should try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish does not cache a page that sets cookies and in the response headers you provided there is a *Set-Cookie* there.

To address this issue you can follow two paths:

- Continue to **avoid caching** those pages with *Set-Cookie*;
- **Remove all *Set-Cookie*** from the pages you want to cache;
- Or put all the manipulation separated from the page you want to cache and call it through *AJAX*.